# What does : ${param:=value} mean?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I read the following in [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html#l33):

> A synonym for ‘true’ is ‘:’; it’s often used in this form to give
>   arguments which have side effects but which shouldn’t be used —
>   something like

```
: ${param:=value}
```

> which is a common idiom in all Bourne shell derivatives. In the
>   parameter expansion, `$param` is given the value value if it was empty
>   before, and left alone otherwise. Since that was the only reason for
>   the parameter expansion, you use `:` to ignore the argument. Actually,
>   the shell blithely builds the command line — the colon, followed by
>   whatever the value of `$param` is, whether or not the assignment
>   happened — then executes the command; it just so happens that ‘:’
>   takes no notice of the arguments it was given.

but I don't understand it. I get that `:` means `true`, but there are two colons in the expression. As a minor question, why is this idiom used so much in all Bourne shell derivatives? What purpose does it serve?

**Note:**
I am interested in what this idiom does in both **bash** and in **zsh**.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for `zsh` or `bash`?

Comment: @enzotib, I'm interested in both. I clarified that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's break this down into pieces.

This code runs the command `:` with some arguments. The command `:` does nothing and ignores its arguments. Therefore the whole command line does nothing, except whatever side effects happen in the arguments.

The syntax `${parameter_name:=value}` exists in all non-antique Bourne-style shells, including ash, bash, ksh and zsh. It sets the parameter to a default if necessary. It is equivalent to

```
if [ -z "$parameter_name" ]; then parameter_name=value; fi
… ${parameter_name}
```

In other words, if `parameter_name` is not set or is set to an empty value, then set it to the indicated value; and then run the command, using the new parameter value. There is a variant, `${parameter_name=value}`, which leaves the parameter empty if it was empty, only using the indicated value if the parameter was unset.

You'll find this syntax documented under “parameter expansion” in [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), and the dash, bash, ksh and zsh manuals.

There are variations on this syntax, in particular `${parameter_name:-value}` which let you use a default value for this expansion only, without assigning to the parameter.

In summary, `: ${parameter_name:=value}` is a concise way of writing

```
if [ -z "$parameter_name" ]; then parameter_name=value; fi
```

Answer (score 15):

`:` does not mean true -- you're probably thinking of `while :`, but even in that expression it doesn't mean "true", it merely happens evaluate to it (in fact, it is simply a null command, or noop).

This parameter expansion (`${x:=y}`) means "assign *y* to *x* if *x* is unset or empty, and expand the eventual value of *x*".

```
$ echo "${foo:=bar}"
bar
$ foo=baz
$ echo "${foo:=bar}"
baz
$ foo=
$ echo "${foo:=bar}"
bar
$ echo "${foo}"
bar
```

The Bash Hackers wiki has a good article on parameter expansion [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

The reason that `:` is used is so that whilst other parts of the command are evaluated, they are not acted upon (as `:` is a null command). Thus, you have `${x:=y}` perform its function without affecting anything else, for example, if you didn't have the `:` at the beginning, it would try to execute a command called *y*.

Here is `bash`'s help page on `:`:

```
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

Answer (score 3):

The first `:` is a command, it's called a "noop" or "no operation".  As said in the manpage, it is often used to evaluate the arguments.

The second `:` is a qualifier in the variable expansion - technically it is `:=`.  Which as said, this sets the value if it does not have a value.

Idiom-wise, if you need a default value of an environment variable, then you can use this syntax.  For example, when running a program through `cron(8)`, the environment is not set and and the shell's dot files are not run.  So you may need to set some defaults.

```
: ${JAVA_HOME:=/usr/local/jdk-1.6.0_28}
```

Then you can 'set it and forget it' (until the default jvm changes).