# Bash parameter expansion `substituted` versus `assigned`

Tags: bash

I am looking at parameter expansion using `${parameter:-word}` versus `${parameter:=word}`.

[Here is some relevant documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> `${parameter:-word}` If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
> word is substituted.
>
> `${parameter:=word}` If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
> word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then
> substituted.

Certainly, the key difference is in the first sentence of each description, substituted versus assigned.

But in actuality, I do not know what happens when something is `substituted` versus when something is `assigned`.

Finally, when is it appropriate to use one versus the other?

Comment: But if $parameter is **not** null or unset then this expression doesn't appear to do any assigning or substituting.

Comment: Looks like the end result is the same.  But `echo "${parameter:-word}"` does not actually assign word to `parameter` immediately,

Comment: I am using getopt to pass directory name and file type extensions.  Am setting defaults with `dir=${dir:-$PWD}` and `fltype=${fltype:="texi,org"}`.  But I do not know whether to use  `:-` or `:=`.

Comment: Related: [What does : ${param:=value} mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/what-does-param-value-mean) and [Using “${a:-b}” for variable assignment in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts)

Comment: It is still not clear to me the usefulness of using `${parameter:-word}`  rather than `${parameter:=word}`.

Comment: The difference isn’t ‘‘substituted versus assigned’’, it’s ‘‘assigned versus not assigned’’.  Something gets substituted either way.

Answer (score 7):

Consider this example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "${parameter:-a}"
echo "${parameter:-b}"
echo "${parameter:=c}"
echo "${parameter:=d}"
```

And an example run of the script:

```
$ bash ex.sh
a
b
c
c
```

In the first `echo`, `parameter` is unset, so `a` is *substituted*.  This prints `a`.

In the second `echo`, `parameter` is still unset, so `b` is *substituted*.  This prints `b`.

In the third `echo`, `parameter` is still unset, so `parameter` is *assigned* the value `c`, then `parameter` is evaluated.  This prints `c`.

In the fourth echo, `parameter` *is* *set* (it was set to `c` in the previous statement), so its value is printed.  This prints `c` again.

From this, you can see that `${parameter:-word}` evaluates to `word` if `parameter` is unset or null, but does not affect the *value* of `parameter`, while `${parameter:=word}` will set the *value* of `parameter` if it was unset of null.

Comment: Thank you for the example.  One thing I cannot figure out are the circumstances that would push you to use `${parameter:-a}`.  I currently use `${parameter:=d}` to set default parameters for function arguments.

Comment: @Pietru you can use `${parameter:-word}` if you want the script to be able to determine that `parameter` was unset/null after you initially try to use its value.

Comment: Does your comment also mean that I can do `varp=${parameter:-word}` ?  Meaning set `varp` to `word` without setting `parameter`.  However, I do not see a difference using `parameter=${parameter:-word}` and `parameter=${parameter:=word}`.

Comment: @Pietru _Does your comment also mean...?_ Yes.  _However, I do not see a difference..._ There really isn't a difference in that case.

Comment: Some people denigrate the use of `parameter=${parameter:=word}`, as it is a form of parameter expansion that intrinsically performs variable assignment, only to redundantly assign the result of the expansion to the same variable once again.  How is `${parameter:=word}` customarily used ?

Comment: The solution would then be to use `: ${parameter:=word}`